# How do I stop postgres from taking up the whole terminal with blank space after my query?

Tags: linux, postgresql, psql, fedora

Lately whenever I run psql queries in my terminal it clears the screen and adds a bunch of blank space. I feel like this has started happening since I upgraded to Fedora 36 but am not sure.

[image: Query output]

I am trying to get it back to normal and just output the query result like any other command you run, by just appending the result after my last command

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) would be better places to ask this question.

Comment: The output is being paged. Check `man psql` or the PSQL section in the PostgreSQL docs for informtion about pager settings.

Comment: @DanBonachea Oh ok, noted. I didn't know postgres was Unix specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Found the answer*

I had the pager turned on and I was able to use the `\pset pager` command to turn it off.

[postgresql.org/docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/app-psql.html)